# Converting TrueType font to web

Tags: webfonts

Is it possible to find `Font ubuntu` with Polish characters? I've found it on fontsquirell but cant download web kit because of license, and they redirect me to converter. But this converter doesn't provide me Ubuntu with Polish characters. Is any way to do this?

Comment: Ubuntu is available via http://www.google.com/fonts , tried that?

Comment: yea, but i dont know how to make it work with polish characters ;) cant find the option there or im just stupid ;) I added from google, but polish doesnt work.